# How to update/refresh DOM item after insert jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I try to figure out how to update the element LI after use insertBefore function jQuery.

The problem is after add any new elements to UL, I can not delete the element same,(with emailTagRemove).

See the demo to see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/HsRfH/

```
<div class="content"> 
    <span class="">Please, insert one or more emails: </span> 
    <br />
    <ul id="ulEmailsCotacao" class="ulEmailsCotacao">
        <li class="liEmailTagNew">
            <input type="text" class="emailInputTag" name="" value="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
  //if enter, tab or space, add new value
  $('.emailInputTag').keydown(function (e) {
      var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
      if (key === 13 || key === 9 || key === 32) {
          addEmail();
      }
  });

  addEmail = function () {
      var email = $('.emailInputTag').val().trim();
      $('<li class="liEmailTagChoiced">' + email + '<a id="del" class="emailTagRemove">x</a></li>').insertBefore('.liEmailTagNew');
      $('.emailInputTag').val("");
  };

  $('.emailTagRemove').click(function () {
      var email = $(this).parents("li");
      email.remove();
  });
```

Comment: In the future, please post all relevant code directly in the question.

Answer (score 15):

You'd need to use [**event delegation**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for this, due to the elements being added/removed dynamically:

```
 $('.content').on('click', '.emailTagRemove', function () {                
      var email = $(this).parents("li");
      email.remove();
 });
```

Use `.content` as the selector as it's more efficient than using `document` in this case.

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HsRfH/3/)**

Comment: using `#ulEmailsCotacao` instead of `'.content'` will be good too ;) but it purely depends and has to decided by OP

Answer (score 0):

Because those are *dynamically added elements to the existing HTML*, so you need to delegate it using [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler attachment with the `document`.

```
$(document).on('click','.emailTagRemove', function () {                
                var email = $(this).parents("li");
                email.remove();
            });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsRfH/2/)**

As @null pointed using the *static selector* instead of *document* is good, *in order to avoid **conflict** among those elements in entire code.*

```
$('#ulEmailsCotacao').on('click','.emailTagRemove', function () {                
                var email = $(this).parents("li");
                email.remove();
            });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HsRfH/5/)