# script not executing for appended data but executing for prewritten html code inside form, also script is already loaded in top of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a code where i on click on #add it appends some html which have unique class name with them. The code is appended something like this

```
<script>
    var x = 1;
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("#form").last().append('<input name="item' + x + '" placeholder="name" type="text" class="jj' + x + '"/><input type="text" class="xx' + x + '" name="some' + x + '">');
        x = x + 1;
    });
</script>
```

Also i have scripts written for these classes already loaded at starting of the page

```
<script>
    var npp = "something";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //o
        $(".jj").click(function() {
            $(".xx").val(npp);
        });
        //1
        $(".jj1").click(function() {
            $(".xx1").val(npp);
        });
        //2
        $(".jj2").click(function() {
            $(".xx2").val(npp);
        });
        //3
        $(".jj3").click(function() {
            $(".xx3").val(npp);
        });
    });
</script>
```

in console it shows no error, but also the script isn't executing for the elements added by append function, also the script is being executed for first element already present in html inside form.

```
<form id="form" action="..." method="post">
<input type="text" name="item" class="jj">
<input type="text" name="some" class="xx">
</form>
<button id="add">Add new field</button>
```

My actual is somewhat different but the basic functioning/logic is same. Kindly advice why my script isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good answer explaining your problem: [Read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22874008/2160958) with examples

And I quote:

> Because those are dynamically added elements to the existing HTML, so
>   you need to delegate it using [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event
>   handler attachment with the document.

so instead of:

```
$(".jj").click(function(){
  $(".xx").val(npp);
});
```

do:

```
$("body").on('click' , '.jj', function () {                
  $(".xx").val(npp);
});
```

And so on...

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge,this thought never crossed my mind that "on" event handler might be the solution.

Comment: Also is this valid like make an input null entry with same class everywhere and then count the number of classes every time #add is clicked then using for loop rewrite the script inside the loop where classes names will be like " .jj'+x' " if the loop is for(x=0;x<count(class);x++); ?

Comment: because with my current script it fixes the max number of elements script is valid to, any way to make it dynamic like whenever new element is created by append() the script is also appended with their class names ?

Comment: why do you need different class names? can't you just use one class name ? and count elements of that class ?

Comment: well i am performing mathematical operations on these classes thats why i give every element a different class name unlike id so that operation is limited to that particular class only

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.click` function use `on` to be applied on any elements you add to your html code.

Example:

```
      $("body").on('click' , '.jj2' , function(){
        $(".xx2").val(npp);
      });
```